# Centering paper-item text

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I'm new to Polymer, and I'm failing to center the text of an element.
I have this code that represents menu items

```
<paper-item flex center>Element1</paper-item>
<paper-item flex center horizontal>Element2</paper-item>
<paper-item flex>Element3</paper-item>
<paper-item flex>Element4</paper-item>
<paper-item flex>Element5</paper-item>
```

The `flex` works but the center doesn't.
Maybe I need to do this in CSS? But what should I put in CSS to just center those Elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

`<paper-item center-justified flex>Element2</paper-item>`

See [here](http://jsbin.com/ravuzuro/5/edit?html,output).

Comment: Wow awesome! I didn't know that one would do that, should have tested everything. Thanks.

Comment: Or just checkout the official [docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `center-center` attribute on most polymer element which will center an element both horizontally and vertically.

```
<paper-item  center-center>Element2</paper-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this layout

```
<paper-item  flex horizontal layout center center-justified>Element2</paper-item>
```

and `center center-justified` is for vertical way